# What is the fastest algorithm for this assignment problem?

Tags: algorithms

I have a 2x2 grid and I have 5 tokens. I want to place 4 of the 5 tokens on the grid.

Each token has a different value depending on where they are placed on the grid. Essentially if they should not be placed in a certain position they are awarded a value of 20, otherwise they have a score lower than 20.

I am writing a program that needs to figure out which 4 tokens should be placed, in order to use the ones with the lowest value possible.

I need this part of the program to be as fast as possible. I'm wondering if there is an optimal algorithm I should use. I have been researching and came across the Hungarian algorithm but I'm wondering if there is another option I should be considering.

Here is an example of the problem:

My grid has its' positions labelled, a,b,c,d ...

`+--------+--------+
|   c    |   d    |
|        |        |
+--------+--------+
|   a    |   b    |
|        |        |
+--------+--------+`

And I have the following tokens with corresponding values for each location on the grid...

           `a   b   c   d
token_p = [20, 20, 15, 20]
token_r = [ 1,  1, 20, 20]
token_s = [15, 20, 20, 20]
token_t = [20, 10, 20, 10]
token_u = [20, 20,  5, 20]`

The answer should be:

token_s = a (value 15)

token_r = b (value 1)

token_u = c (value 5)

token_t = d (value 10)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a weighted $K_{t, n}$ graph, with tokens in one partition and grid slots on the other, and use a greedy bipartite matching algorithm.

Here is a tutorial on general bipartite matching: http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/304719-data-structures-graph-theory-bipartite-matching/

You will have to adapt it for a greedy approach.